# SQL replace from list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure our how I can replace a string using data from another table

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Id Translation
1  Peter
2  Sandra
3  Olga
```

Now I want to select all and replace the translations using a list that looks like this:

```
Original New
e        #
r        ?
lg       *%
```

So that the select list looks like this:

```
Id  Translation
1   P#t#?
2   Sand?a
3   O*%a
```

So, for each translation, I need to have a REPLACE(Translation,Original,New).
Or in other words: I need to go through every "Translation" in my first list and make another loop in my replacement table to see what to replace

Bare in mind that the first list has 25'000 rows and the second has 50'000, so I can't just type it by hand :)

## EDIT

Just to clarify:
The Original and New from my look up table can be both letters and words so the table can looks like this:

```
Original New
one      two
three    fifty
sun      moon
```

Comment: There's a time and a place for use of cursors, I think you just found one.  I don't think a cross join and using set based activity would work here as each replace would be different.  and there's a possibility of overlapping replacements for example if you have `er` and `e` being replaced then which takes precedent? So I think you want a cursor, ordering from max length in table B to shortest.

Comment: @Marcus Ohlsson: How would you translate 'Peter' if 'et' = '§' and 'te' = '$'?

Comment: And is it guaranteed that New contains no letters that exist in Original? (Even a simple example like 'S' => 'r' and 'ra' => '#' would already lead to the question whether 'Sandra' has to become 'rand#' or '#nd#'.)

Comment: @Torsten Kettner: The letters in New can be in the original :)

Comment: @Marcus Ohlsson: So far you haven't answered, how to react in a conflict situation. How would you translate 'beggar', when 'beg' -> 'abc' and 'egg' -> 'def'? Then: Is the translated string to be translated again (as in my last example: stop at 'rand#' or keep going till '#nd#')? You *do* notice that the main problem with your request is that you fail to state the rules you want applied, don't you?

Answer (score 9):

To do this in one query, you need to use a recursive CTE.  Something like:

```
with trans as (
      select t.original, t.new, row_number() over (order by t.original) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from translations
     ),
     t as (
      select tt.id, tt.string, replace(tt.string, trans.original, trans.new) as replaced,
             seqnum + 1 as seqnum, cnt
      from totranslate tt join
           trans
           on trans.id = 1
      union all
      select t.id, t.string, replace(t.string, trans.original, trans.new),
             seqnum + 1 as seqnum, cnt
      from t join
           trans
           on t.seqnum = trans.id
      where t.seqnum <= t.cnt
     )
select t.id, t.string, t.replaced
from t
where seqnum = cnt;
```

Comment: Correct answer. Only minor quibble. add `OPTION (maxrecursion 0)`

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff and ughai, I've tryed to implement the code but I think it's limited to just use one letter at the time. I need it to work with words as well, sorry for not clarify that in my question, I will update my question :)

Comment: @MarcusOhlsson . . . Nothing in this logic restricts any of the strings to having only a single character.

Comment: +1 I've used this exact premise before for a similar problem where I had to implement the equivalent of C#'s String.Replace in SQL. I hated myself a little bit for even thinking of it, but it is useful.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Translate]
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@Str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result nvarchar(max) = @Str;

  SELECT @Result = replace(@Result,Original,New) from dbo.Mappings order BY Pos; 

  RETURN @Result;
END
```

Here I assumed the table containing translations is called `dbo.Mappings` and beside the `Original` and `New` columns you need another column `Pos int` which will be used to determine the order in which the translations are applied (to address the problems mentioned by @Thorsten Kettner in comments)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a expert in SQL, but it seems like your code will find the first replacement only. I really need to find and replace from every line in the "mappings" table

Comment: No, it will replace all the occurences. First of all the `replace` function alone replaces all occurences of `Original` with `New` for a single mapping. Then the `select` around it calls the `replace` for each mapping. Just give it a try.

Comment: @MarcusOhlsson, if you're not an expert why would you reject the idea without trying it first?

Answer (score 5):

Also with recursive cte:

```
DECLARE @translations TABLE
    (
      Id INT ,
      Translation NVARCHAR(20)
    )
INSERT  INTO @translations
VALUES  ( 1, 'Peter' ),
        ( 2, 'Sandra' ),
        ( 3, 'Olga' )

DECLARE @replacements TABLE
    (
      Original VARCHAR(2) ,
      New VARCHAR(2)
    )
INSERT  INTO @replacements
VALUES  ( 'e', '#' ),
        ( 'r', '?' ),
        ( 'lg', '*%' );


WITH    cte1 AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
                 FROM @translations CROSS JOIN @replacements),
        cte2 AS (SELECT Id, rn, REPLACE(Translation, Original, New) AS NTranslation
                 FROM cte1 
                 WHERE rn = 1
                    UNION ALL
                 SELECT c2.Id, c2.rn + 1, REPLACE(c2.NTranslation, c1.Original, c1.New)
                 FROM cte1 c1
                 JOIN cte2 c2 ON c2.Id = c1.Id AND c2.rn + 1 = c1.rn)
SELECT * FROM cte2
WHERE rn = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @replacements)
ORDER BY Id
```

**EDIT:**

```
WITH    cte1 AS (SELECT t.*, p.Id AS Old, p.Code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
                 FROM translations t CROSS JOIN Property p),
        cte2 AS (SELECT Id, rn, REPLACE(Trans, Old, Code) AS NTranslation
                 FROM cte1 
                 WHERE rn = 1
                    UNION ALL
                 SELECT c2.Id, c2.rn + 1, REPLACE(c2.NTranslation, c1.Old, c1.Code)
                 FROM cte1 c1
                 JOIN cte2 c2 ON c2.Id = c1.Id AND c2.rn + 1 = c1.rn)
SELECT * FROM cte2
WHERE rn = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Property)
ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it possible to get the translation and replacement data from tables so I don't have to type 50'000 lines in the function?

Comment: Of Course, just delete everythin before `WITH` and replace `@translations` and `@replacements` with according tables.

Comment: Thank you @Giorgi Nakeuri I'm pretty new to this kind of script, can you please advise me how it would look if Translation comes from column "Trans" in the dbo.translations and Replacement comes from "Id" and "Code" in dbo.Property?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I worked out that will allow you to replace multiple characters with one specified string.

[Split2] is stolen from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitjet/2009/12/11/convert-comma-separated-string-to-table-4-different-approaches/

```
USE <Your Database>
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split2]
( 
@strString varchar(4000)
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE
(
 RID INT IDENTITY(0,1) Primary Key
,Value varchar(4000)
)
AS
    BEGIN
        WITH StrCTE(start, stop) AS
        (
        SELECT 1, CHARINDEX(',' , @strString )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  stop + 1, CHARINDEX(',' ,@strString  , stop + 1)
            FROM StrCTE
            WHERE stop > 0
        )

        INSERT INTO @Result
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@strString , start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop - start ELSE 4000 END) AS stringValue
            FROM StrCTE

        RETURN
    END
GO

USE <Your Database>
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MultiReplace]
(
 @MyString varchar(MAX)
,@RepChars varchar(4000)
,@NewChars varchar(4000)
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @CurRow int = 0
        DECLARE @MaxRow int

        SELECT @MaxRow = MAX(RID)
            FROM dbo.split2 ( @RepChars )

        WHILE @CurRow <= @MaxRow
            BEGIN
                SELECT @MyString = REPLACE(@MyString,VALUE,@NewChars)
                    FROM dbo.split2 ( @RepChars )
                    WHERE RID = @CurRow

                SET @CurRow = @CurRow + 1
            END

        RETURN (@MyString);

    END
GO
```

In this example I replace each character with no space

```
SELECT [dbo].[MultiReplace]('6th month 2016-06 (test / requested)',',1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,(,),/,-,+, ','')
```

Result:
monthtestrequested

I hope this is useful for you.